# Put a link inside an image title. Jquery lightbox plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, hyperlink, lightbox

I have the following code in my website to show portfolio items:

```
<div class="lightCon"> 
<span class="hoverBox"> <span class="smallIcon"> 
<a href="images/projects/big-images/golden-dreams-team.jpg" title="Golden Dreams Team" class="zoom lb lb_warsaw1">
<i class="fa fa-plus fa-2x"></i></a> 
</span> </span>
<img src="images/projects/thumb-images/golden-dreams-team.jpg" alt="Golden Dreams Team Diseño Web HTML5 Boostrap" > 
</div>
```

However, as you can see in the site http://hdeprada.com/webs/nueva/ the title is what it is displaying in the light box when this pops. However, I want to either make the title a link to the live website or to put some more text next to it with a link to it.

I have been trying to put a link inside the title="" tag but it is not working. What can I do? My knowledge in jquery is pretty low so I don´t really know how to edit the plugin to achieve this.